# PHP session variable disapearing after redirect

Tags: php, session

I have been trying to figure this out for the better part of the day. I have gone through at least 2 dozen stack posts regarding this. Basically, I am setting a session variable called message on a page and redirecting to one of a couple different pages and I need to display that message.

I have session_start at the top of all pages
this is the same domain ( `domain.com` to `domain.com` )
I do a `print_r($_SESSION); exit; die;` on the page the message is set right after I set it and right before I redirect it and I see the variable messages is set. Then I go to the page and on the top after `session_start()` I do another `print_r($_SESSION); exit; die;` to view the session and everything except what was set on the previous page is there. This is mind boggling.

What would make just that Session key and value disappear between pages?

Comment: [**`session_start()`**](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Comment: Could you please show the relevant code

Comment: If you are redirecting from `domain.com` to `www.domain.com` you will lose your sessions